# Are any bonds broken when NO2 becomes N2O4?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

This reversible reaction occurs in room condition:

$$\ce{2NO2 <=> N2O4}\quad(\Delta H=-57.23\mbox{ kJ/mol)}$$

This is the Lewis structure of $\ce{NO2}$ (courtesy [Ben Mills](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Benjah-bmm27) via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nitrogen-dioxide-resonance-2D.png)):

[image]

This is the Lewis structure of $\ce{N2O4}$ (courtesy [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.23681.html)):

[image]

To me, it seems that no bonds need to be broken for the forward reaction ($\ce{2NO2 -> N2O4}$) to occur, which is strange indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No bonds are broken, but there are several isomers of N2O4.  The unpaired electron can be on either the N or the O, for each NO2 molecule. The long bond between the monomers involves these two unpaired electrons.

See sections 7-1 to 7-3 of [Bonding in Electron-Rich Molecules: Qualitative Valence-Bond Approach via Increased-valence Structures](https://books.google.com/books?id=cLzYCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&dq=charge%20on%20N%20atom%20in%20NO2&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF9-qP9bbOAhUQ0WMKHRsiAfgQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=charge%20on%20N%20atom%20in%20NO2&f=false) for more information.

According to [First-Principles Study of the Role of Interconversion Between NO2, N2O4, cis-ONO-NO2, and trans-ONO-NO2 in Chemical Processes](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja300545e) J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2012, 134 (31), pp 12970–12978:

there is no barrier to the bonding of two monomers to form the planar isomer with the N-N bond.

Comment: So the energy diagram (enthalpy) would have no uprise; only downfall?

Comment: @user34388  There is no barrier for the formation of the isomer with the N-N bond, see the reference I just added to the answer

Answer (score 6):

As stated by @DavePhD no bonds are broken. The $\ce{NO2}$ is a brown paramagnetic gas with the single electron mainly located on the nitrogen, and $\ce{N2O4}$ a colourless and diamagnetic gas. This molecule has a very long N-N bond, 0.178 nm, the O-N-O angle is 134 degrees the same as in $\ce{NO2}$. (The single bond in $\ce{H2NNH2}$ is 0.147 nm). The bond appears to be mainly of a $\sigma$ nature but delocalised over the molecule. (ref Ahlrichs & Keil J.A.C.S. 1974,96,7615) 
Although there are 3 isomeric forms the most stable by far in the solid and liquid has the geometry you show in the question. The structure $\ce{O-N-O-NO2}$ is observed at 4 k in infra-red spectra. This structure may be important in some reactions even in the gas phase but this is speculative. The $\ce{N2O4}$ is planar at room temperature but twisted in an inert matrix at low temperature; this is the third isomeric form.