# Is it possible that for a reaction, it's activation energy equals total enthalpy of reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there any reaction for which activation energy equals total change in enthalpy for the reaction . Is it possible in the first place ? Are there any interesting examples relating this concept ?

Comment: That would imply zero barrier for the reverse reaction, BTW.

Comment: What can we say about homolytic fission of... say chlorine molecule ?

Comment: Yeah, maybe something like that.

Comment: So we can say that activation energy for homolytic fission is same as  enthalpy change for overall reaction ? It's confusing

Comment: @getafix any help ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you mean by total change in enthalpy?

Comment: Sorry for that ambiguity. I meant the heat of reaction . Or total enthalpy of reaction .

Comment: As Ivan said I guess $\ce{2Cl. -> Cl2}$ would fit the bill. Reverse reaction pretty much has no activation energy.

Comment: @orthocresol Did you mean $\ce{Cl2 -> 2Cl*}$?

Comment: Yes, I did. $\ce{}$

Answer (score 1):

According to [DavePhD](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/58565/34388), the following reaction satisfies the requirement:

$$\ce{O2N-NO2 -> 2NO2}$$