# What is the mechanism for the auto-dissociation of nitrogen tetraoxide

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, solvents

How does nitrogen tetraoxide dissociate into nitrosyl ion and nitrate ion?

Is it similar to the auto-dissociation of $\ce{SO2}$ into thionyl ion and sulfite ion by acceptance and donation of oxide ion?

I couldn't find a mechanism for the auto-dissociation of nitrogen tetraoxide.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that $$\ce{N2O4 <=> NO+ + NO3-}$$ is actually happening and under which conditions? Maybe then one would be able to also find mechanistic evidence. I would actually be surprised when this would be more feasible than $$\ce{N2O4 <=>2NO2}.$$

Comment: Are you interested in the gas-phase dissociation? Liquid-phase dissociation? Dissociation in aqueous media?

Comment: Maybe you confused it with N2O5 which is comprised of nitronium and nitrate ion?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/are-any-bonds-broken-when-no2-becomes-n2o4

Answer (score 7):

Dinitrogen tetroxide $\ce{N2O4}$ is a *colourless* liquid composed of planar dimers of nitrogen dioxide $\ce{NO2}$.$^{[1]\ \text{[a]}\ [2]}$

[image: Nitrogen dioxide dimerisation. Chemsketch and reference [1]]

As [Martin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4945/martin-%e3%83%9e%e3%83%bc%e3%83%81%e3%83%b3) noted and is to be expected from the structure of $\ce{N2O4}$, the process

$$\ce{N2O4 <=> NO+ + NO3-}$$

is not very likely to happen. Autoionisation of $\ce{NO2}$ is more common$^{[1]}$.

$$\ce{NO2 -> NO2+ +  e^-\\ NO2 +  e^- -> NO2-}$$

Ionisation energy of $\ce{NO2}$ is $9.8\ \mathrm{eV}$ while its electron affinity equals $1.62\ \mathrm{eV}$.$^{[1]}$ Technically you could look at this as heterolytic bond dissociation $\ce{N2O4}$ but that is probably not what is happening. This autoionisation is, in a way, realised for aqueous solutions$^{[2]}$:

$$\ce{\underset{electron transfer}{NO2 + NO2} + H2O -> \underset{really just HNO3}{NO2OH} +  HNO2},$$
$$\ce{\underset{electron transfer}{NO2 + NO2} + 2KOH -> KNO3 + KNO2 +  H2O}.$$

<sub>**Table 1.** Melting and poiling points of $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{N2O4}$. Note the "equality" of melting points.$^{[2]\ [3]}$</sub>
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{Molecule} & \mathbf{mp\ (\deg  \mathrm{C})} &  \mathbf{bp\ (\deg  \mathrm{C})}\\
\hline
\ce{NO2} & -11.2 & 21 \\
\ce{N2O4} & -11.2 & 22 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$

<sub>**Table 2.** Percentage of  $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{N2O4}$ at various temperatures (pressure $1 \ \mathrm{atm}$).$^{[2]}$</sub>
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{Molecule} & \text{below}\  \mathrm{mp}\ (\mathrm{\%}) &  \mathbf{40\ \deg  \mathrm{C}\ (\mathrm{\%})} & \text{over}\mathbf{\  150\deg  \mathrm{C}\ (\mathrm{\%})}\\
\hline
\ce{NO2} & 0 & 31 & 100 \\
\ce{N2O4} & 100 & 69 & 0 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$

---

$\text{[a]}$ To the best of my knowledge, the enthalpy $-55\ \mathrm{kJ}$ applies at $20 \deg \mathrm{C}$ and $1\  \mathrm{atm}$ for both components in the gas phase. NIST gives $-57.12\ \mathrm{kJ}$ at $25 \deg \mathrm{C}$ and $1\  \mathrm{bar}$. See [$\ce{N2O4}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C10544726&Mask=1#) and [$\ce{NO2}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C10102440&Mask=1#Thermo-Gas).

---

$[1]$ N. N. Ahmetov. *Anorgaaniline keemia*. (1974) (pages 375, 376)

$[2]$ H. Karik, Kalle Truus. *Elementide keemia*. (2003) (pages 424, 426)

$[3]$ Wikipedia:

- [Nitrogen dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide)
- [Dinitrogen tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide)